# Login with facebook possibility

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, web-applications

I have a question about a facebook login on my webapplication.

Users can either login with facebook or register manually. 
After registering manually, the user is added to the database 'users'.
When users login with facebook for the first time, the same happens (however, no password is added to the database)

My question: is it possible to allow people that have logged in with facebook to use the 'normal' login form, the one that the users that have registered manually? How to check if the password that the user has entered matches their facebook password?

Or is this completely impossible?

btw, I am using codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way to do this, is to ask them for a password after they sign in. This way, they will be able to login using facebook, or their email address and the password they just specified.

There is no way to make sure the password is the same as Facebook's, and I don't recommend going that way, even if that was possible (Not possible and will get you into trouble with facebook TOS). It's up to your users to choose the password they want.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best possibility is to give users the ability to create a password for they accounts because you can´t exchange passwords with Facebook (it's the base of the use of OAuth, not known the user password on the external provider).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite simple actually and I've done it on more than one occasion. Add to that I think it's good practice, Facebook has been known to change their API and screw up FB logins in the past.

You can do it in one of two ways.

The first requires no user interaction but isn't the safest way to do things nor is it a good idea for any site that needs to be truly secure. Simply generate a random password when entering the user data for the first time and email it to the user on their FB email. The problems are, first emailing passwords can be dangerous security wise and second a lot of people use throw away email accounts for FB so they may never see the email.

Second is through user interaction on a user control panel. Simply allow them to update their password field. For users logged in via FB you can't ask for previous password but you could use some other data scraped from the FB account, even asking for their FB email address would be somewhat secure since FB obscures that information from the general public now.

**No, there is no way to get their FB password, and no Facebook is never going to change their API to allow that.**